# Changing image dynamically on a dynamic list on Android

Tags: java, android, list, layout, dynamic

I have created an app with a listview with arrayadapter that the user can dynamically populate. I store the info entered as a json string in the preferences and when I refresh the app, I get the list with the entries. The thing is that I want the image next to each entry to change after a network operation. The problem I'm facing seems to be that since the elements in the list are added dynamically, I dont seem to find a good way neither to update the imageview on the onPostExecute() method, either to be able to target each entry specifically since they share the same layout ids.

Here is my getView() method inside my adapter:

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.deviceName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_pc_name);
            holder.deviceIp = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_pdt_desc);
            holder.devicePort = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_pdt_price);
            holder.favoriteImg = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Devices device = (Devices) getItem(position);
        holder.deviceName.setText(device.getName());
        holder.deviceIp.setText(device.getIpOnline());
        holder.devicePort.setText(device.getPortOnline() + "");              


        return convertView;
    }
```

Here is my AsyncTask:

```
public class Connection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

   private String ipOnline;
   private int portOnline;
   private String ipWol;
   private int portWol;
   private String macAddress;
   private ImageView img;
   private Context context;
    public interface AsyncResponse {
        void processFinish(String output);
    }



     public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

        public Connection(Context mContext, ImageView Img,String IpOnline, int PortOnline, String IpWol, int PortWol, String MacAddress, AsyncResponse delegate) {
            ipOnline = IpOnline;
            portOnline = PortOnline;
            ipWol = IpWol;
            portWol = PortWol;
            macAddress = MacAddress;
            context = mContext;
          //  inflate = Inflate;
            img = Img;
           // spin = spinner;
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }
        public int status;

        @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(lastContext);
            try  {
                Socket echoSocket = new Socket();
                echoSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ipOnline,portOnline),2000);

                if(echoSocket.isConnected())
                    status = 1;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                status = 0;
            }
            if(status == 0)
                return "0";
            else
                return "1";
       }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
           super.onPostExecute(result);
ImageView img = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite);
               if (status == 0)
                   img.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.presence_offline);
               else
                   img.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.presence_online);
    delegate.processFinish(result);  
       }   
    }
```

And here is my call to it:

```
new Connection(activity, img, product.getIpOnline(), Integer.parseInt(product.getPortOnline()), product.getIpWol(), Integer.parseInt(product.getPortWol()), product.getMacAddress(), new Connection.AsyncResponse() {
                        @Override
                        public void processFinish(String output) {
                        }
                    }).execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution.

I created a public variable on my adapter and I'm adding all the images:

```
public List<ImageView> allImages = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

public List<ImageView> getAllImages(){
        return this.allImages;
    }

this.allImages.add((ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite));
```

Then on my fragmented activity onCreateView method I deployed a delayed runnable:

```
(new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateStatus();
                }
            }, 500);
```

the updateStatus() method initializes the images variable and begins network checks to determine which image to use. Then it applies it accordingly.

```
public void updateStatus() {
        List<ImageView> images = deviceListAdapter.getAllImages();
        if(count > 0 && images.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < deviceListAdapter.getCount() ; i++) {
                Devices product = (Devices) deviceListAdapter.getItem(i);
                if((TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(product.getPortOnline()) && TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(product.getPortWol())) && (!product.getPortOnline().isEmpty() && !product.getPortWol().isEmpty()))  {
                    new Connection(activity, images.get(i), product.getIpOnline(), Integer.parseInt(product.getPortOnline()), product.getIpWol(), Integer.parseInt(product.getPortWol()), product.getMacAddress(), new Connection.AsyncResponse() {
                        @Override
                        public void processFinish(Boolean output) {
                        }
                    }).execute();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It might not be optimal but feel free to add a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use view holder pattern or recyclerview .

You need to store the reference of image view in holder and can update the image with the help of this reference instead of id of view

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ive already implemented a view holder pattern however the problem is that when calling my Async class in order to perform the network operation, the getView keeps calling it all the time and the images take some time to refresh. Am I doing something wrong?I attached my getView method.

Comment: Just post you code snippets for async task and its call